# Getting Error While Oracle DB Connection (save method) by using Spring (Hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to save and read data from Oracle DB applicaiton. In order to that I tried to use spring & hibernate but when I am trying to save data to DB, I am getting "Can't get Id field from Entry " error. Do you have any ide about that.

Applcaiton Properties;

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxx
spring.datasource.username=USER_T
spring.datasource.password=S_USER_T
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT * from dual
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

When I tried to save an Entity to DB with Spring Boot web application, I am getting following error

```
`2020-11-26 09:50:10.665 ERROR 5748 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; ne`sted exception is org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.InvalidEntryException: Can't get Id field from Entry com.tcdata.wstcdata.model.TestRequestModel@6f7f923b; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.MetaDataException: Class class com.tcdata.wstcdata.model.TestRequestModel must have a class level interface org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry annotation] with root cause

org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.MetaDataException: Class class com.tcdata.wstcdata.model.TestRequestModel must have a class level interface org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry annotation
    at org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.ObjectMetaData.<init>(ObjectMetaData.java:112) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.addManagedClass(DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.java:151) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.getEntityData(DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.java:108) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.getIdField(DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.java:428) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.odm.core.impl.DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.getId(DefaultObjectDirectoryMapper.java:420) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.support.SimpleLdapRepository.save(SimpleLdapRepository.java:105) ~[spring-data-ldap-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.ImplementationInvocationMetadata.invoke(ImplementationInvocationMetadata.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:155) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.tcdata.wstcdata.controller.TestController.testSystem(TestController.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]
```

REST Controller

```
 @RestController
    public class TestController {
    
        @Autowired
        private TCDATAInterfaceRepository tCDATAInterfaceRepository;
        
        @Autowired
        private TestRequestRepository testRequestRepository;
        
        @RequestMapping(value="/request/test",method=RequestMethod.GET, produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
        public @ResponseBody ReturnResponseBodyModel testSystem(@RequestBody TestServiceModel requestModel) {
            ReturnResponseBodyModel responseModel = new ReturnResponseBodyModel();
            System.out.println(" ---------------------> " + requestModel.getName());
            responseModel.setResponseCode("0");
            responseModel.setResponseDescription("web service worked");
            
             TestRequestModel testRequestModel = new TestRequestModel();
             testRequestModel.setSystemName("QBCD");
             testRequestModel.setSystemType("Oracle");
             
             System.out.println(" ---------------------> " + "before save");
             this.testRequestRepository.save(testRequestModel);
            
            return responseModel;
        
        }
        
        
    }
```

DB Model;

```
package com.tcdata.wstcdata.model;


@Entity
@Table(name = "XXX_TEST")
public class TestRequestModel {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "C_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "C_SEQ", sequenceName = "XXX_TEST_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
private Long Id;

@Column(name="SYSTEM_NAME", nullable=false)
private String systemName;

@Column(name="SYSTEM_TYPE", nullable=false)
private String systemType;

public Long getId() {
    return Id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    Id = id;
}
public String getSystemName() {
    return systemName;
}
public void setSystemName(String systemName) {
    this.systemName = systemName;
}
public String getSystemType() {
    return systemType;
}
public void setSystemType(String systemType) {
    this.systemType = systemType;
}
```

}

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface TestRequestRepository extends CrudRepository<TestRequestModel, Long>{
//  TestRequestModel findById(long id);
}
```

Comment: Add a `Constructor` to your class

Comment: The stack trace is complaining about ldap, is there something about it in the code? Otherwise it doesn't look so bad. You may check out https://bootify.io, you can create an app for oracle with your entity and rest controller.